# Como criar um índice condicional no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, índices

Como criar um índice filtrado por uma faixa específica de dados?

Até onde eu sei, é impossível fazer isso diretamente no MySQL. Em alguns outros sistemas de banco de dados geralmente há uma cláusula `WHERE` para esse filtro.

Alguns sistemas usam outro nome para esse tipo de índice: [índice parcial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-partial.html) ou [índice baseado em função](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS005) ou ainda [índice filtrado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Por exemplo: eu quero criar um índice que apenas contenha chaves para linhas com uma característica específica, algo como `status = 'ATIVO'`.

Eu posso ter uma tabela muito grande e para determinadas *queries* frequentes que certamente só precisam dos dados "ativos" e que não são uma porção tão grande da tabela. Neste caso ter um índice com chaves para todas linhas da tabela seria um desperdício de recursos.

O exemplo citado é uma expressão simples, mas poderia usar qualquer outra expressão.

Se não for possível nada parecido, há alternativas para ter o índice de forma mais eficiente?

Comment: Se a sua preocupação é somente com o uso de recursos, não tem muito o que fazer, já que o MySQL não suporta esse tipo de índice. Se houver preocupação com performance, talvez seja possível otimizar as queries, mas isso vai depender de análise dos planos de execução específicos.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O MySQL atualmente não tem suporte a índices condicionais.

O melhor *reparo técnico*<sup>1</sup> que eu vejo para este caso específico é criar uma tabela auxiliar com as seguintes características:

```sql
CREATE TABLE  `meu_schema`.`tabela_auxiliar` (
   `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Na tabela principal você adiciona três *triggers*<sup>2</sup>, com a seguinte especificação:

```sql
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER exemplo_parcial_insert AFTER INSERT ON tabela_principal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.status = 'ATIVO' THEN
      REPLACE tabela_auxiliar SET tabela_auxiliar.id = NEW.id;
   END IF;
END;//

CREATE TRIGGER exemplo_parcial_update AFTER UPDATE ON tabela_principal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.status = 'ATIVO' THEN
      REPLACE tabela_auxiliar SET tabela_auxiliar.id = NEW.id;
   ELSE
      DELETE FROM tabela_auxiliar WHERE tabela_auxiliar.id = OLD.id;
   END IF;
END;//

CREATE TRIGGER exemplo_parcial_delete AFTER DELETE ON tabela_principal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM tabela_auxiliar WHERE tabela_auxiliar.id = OLD.id;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

> O uso do delimiter `//` é necessário, pois queremos que os `;` façam parte dos *triggers*.

Assim, automaticamente a tabela auxiliar terá exatamente os IDs correspondente às entradas cujo status é a string "ATIVO", sendo atualizada pelos *triggers* nas condições normais de uso.

> Caso você queira, [além de filtrar, indexar por alguma coluna em específico](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57347/33203), adicione-a na tabela auxiliar com índice simples, e nos `replace` dos triggers.

Para usar esta tabela auxiliar num select, basta um `join` convencional:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabela_auxiliar LEFT JOIN tabela_principal
   ON tabela_principal.id = tabela_auxiliar.id;
```

Óbvio que se a tabela principal já estiver com dados, você deve preencher a tabela auxiliar com os IDs que atingirem a condição desejada. Para isto, basta usar a query abaixo uma vez:

```sql
INSERT INTO tabela_auxiliar SET id = tabela_principal.id
   WHERE tabela_principal.status="ATIVO";
```

Quanto à performance, vai depender dos testes caso a caso, e da quantia de detecções positivas para a condição desejada. Esta solução faz mais sentido no caso de parcelas pequenas de resultados positivos. Na prática, só testando mesmo para ver se de fato está economizando algum espaço de fato, e se a queda de performance compensa o "malabarismo".

<sub>1. gambiarra</sub>
<sub>2. pratos de trigo não inclusos.</sub>

Comment: Tristes triggers...

Comment: Ouvi dizer que a versão gratuita do MySQL permite apenas três triggers por banco. Confere?

Answer (score 12):

O MySQL não tem suporte a índices condicionais, porem, o termo **`índices parciais`** é geralmente encontrado na literatura se referindo ao índice de **`prefixo`**, que é um recurso suportado pelo MySQL, veja o exemplo:

Temos uma tabela, com nome de **`usuarios`**, e uma coluna, com nome **`status`** do tipo **`varchar`** de tamanho **`10`**

> CREATE INDEX indice_prefixo_status ON usuarios (status(1));

Isso criará um índice que irá indexar apenas o primeiro caractere, salvando assim uma quantidade imensa de recursos.

Ao Fazer a Consulta, para que esse índice seja utilizado, devemos usar alguma função de manipulação de strings, como **`LEFT`** ou **`SUBSTR`**, veja os exemplos:

1) Obtendo o número de usuários ativos / Inativos, usando a função **`LEFT`**.

```sql
SELECT 
    count(LEFT(status, 1)) as contagem_usuarios, 
    LEFT(status, 1) as status 
FROM 
    usuarios 
GROUP_BY
LEFT(status, 1)
```

2) Obtendo todos os usuários Inativos:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    usuarios
WHERE
    LEFT(status,1) = 'I'
```

Comment: De fato esse tipo de índice pode funcionar em alguns casos, mas não é um substituto genérico para índices condicionais/parciais, dependendo do conteúdo e do tipo da coluna onde se quer aplicar o índice.

Comment: Sim, porem infelizmente o MySQL não traz suporte a tal recurso, isso é (creio eu) o mais próximo que conseguimos chegar

Comment: Concordo, é um caso de "ruim com ele, pior sem ele".

Comment: exatamente isso.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você terá uma melhor performance adicionando uma partição na tabela.

```
CREATE TABLE sua_tabela (campos ..) PARTITION  BY LIST(status) ( PARTITION p_ativos VALUES IN ('ATIVO'), PARTITION p_inativos VALUES IN ('INATIVO'));
```

Esse procedimento divide fisicamente a tabela.