# Como um índice melhora a performance de uma consulta?

Tags: banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Por que a criação de um índice melhora a performance de uma consulta? Alguma modificação na estrutura da tabela é feita? A estrutura de dados para armazenamento em disco é modificada? O algoritmo utilizado para realizar a busca é diferente? O que possibilita a melhoria de desempenho?

Comment: Relacionadas: [O que são os INDEX, B-tree, hash, GiST, e GIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/91), [Vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/91) e [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/91)

Comment: Não é uma duplicata @rray?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55118/como-aplicar-indexes-para-melhorar-a-performance-das-queries)

Comment: Não entendi pq é duplicada... nenhuma das perguntas responde a minha questão que é como um índice funciona, como ele é armazenado no banco de dados, e o mais importante por que ele melhora as consultas...

Comment: existe muitas informações, mas não a que eu pedi, portanto não é duplicada :D

Comment: Não entendi porque negativaram a pergunta...

Comment: Vinculado: [Quando e em quais colunas deve-se usar índices?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76131/18246)

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 13):

[image: It's Magic]

É pura matemágica!

Não vou entrar em detalhes (é verdade :) ), dúvidas específicas podem ser sanadas em novas perguntas.

## Busca binária

O índice de um banco de dados não é nem um pouco diferente de um índice de livro, ou mesmo de um dicionário que é em si um índice.

Como você vai achar a palavra que você quer no meio de muitas milhares de palavras? Você sabe que as palavras estão em ordem alfabética.

Pela primeira letra você já tenta abrir em uma página próxima. Então se for "C" vai abrir mais ou menos no começo, se for "N" vai abrir mais ou menos no meio e se for "S" vai abri próximo do fim.

Aí vai ali por perto olhando na página qual a primeira palavra e ver se o que você procura está mais pra frente ou mais pra trás de onde você está. Vai fazendo isso sucessivamente até achar uma página que esteja muito perto da palavra procurada.

Aí você vai olhando dentro da página pela palavra. Não precisa olhar uma por uma, pode fazer o mesmo tipo de pesquisa que estava fazendo nas páginas. Procura mais ou menos no lugar mais provável que a palavra está na página e vai indo pra cima ou pra baixo se você se aproximou da palavra que quer ou se afastou.

Este tipo de busca é um algoritmo "dividir para conquistar". Se você elimina parte do que está buscando fica mais fácil achar. Se está em alguma ordem fica fácil eliminar uma parte sabendo que o que procura está mais pra frente ou mais pra trás.

Pois bem, na computação fazendo exatamente isto de uma bem estruturada e precisa. Quando temos uma coleção dados em ordem começamos fazer a abusca bem no meio dos dados (talvez compense olhar o primeiro e quem sabe o último elemento dessa coleção de dados).

Se você olha na metade um dado pode ver se o que procura é maior ou menor do que aquilo que encontrou no meio (obviamente se o que está bem no meio não é igual). É uma comparação simples que todo mundo sempre faz, não importa se o dado é um número, uma data, um texto, etc. Se dá para usar o operador de `<` ou `>` tá valendo. Se o que você procura é maior então você descarta a primeira metade da coleção e olha só na segunda metade agora.

Mas não vai olhar tudo na segunda metade. Olha só lá no meio dessa metade, ou seja, na posição dos 3/4 da coleção. Se o elemento que estiver ali for igual, ótimo, já achou o que queria. Se for menor então você descarta essa parte final e passa olhar apenas 1/8 da coleção entre a metade e o 3/4 dela.

E aí faz isso novamente, pegando 1/16 da coleção. Enquanto não achar vai repetindo pegando 1/32, 1/64, 1/28.

Isto é chamada [busca binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Você consegue achar uma informação em 2 bilhões elementos de uma coleção de dados em apenas 32 tentativas (2 elevado 31 dá 2 bilhões aproximadamente, tem que tirar um que é a tentativa inicial). Pode achar em menos operações, pode achar na primeira tentativa. Como curiosidade, se tiver 10 milhões de elementos na coleção demorará no máximo apenas 21 tentativas. Para 4000 leva até 13 tentativas. 1 trilhão leva 41 tentativas. É rápido?

Isso é considerado como [complexidade algorítmica O(log n)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) onde o tempo gasto será o logaritmo de N, sendo que N é a quantidade de elementos da coleção.

A busca binária tem uma desvantagem. A coleção precisa estar sempre em ordem. Então temos ganho grande na busca. Mas seria uma tragédia inserir, modificar o dado ou removê-lo da coleção mantendo a ordem. Teria que reconstruir toda coleção em cada operação dessa. Completamente inviável.

## Árvore binária

Então precisamos organizar a coleção de uma forma que não precise reconstruí-la em cada modificação. Ou pelo menos temos que fazer com que a reconstrução seja minimizada. Ora, de novo caímos em uma situação de "dividir e conquistar".

Então precisamos de uma estrutura de dados que divida a coleção em várias partes, assim toda vez que eu modificar um elemento eu tenho que modificar apenas a parte que ele pertence. Se eu dividir por 2, já tenho que reconstruir apenas metade da coleção, se eu dividir por 4, só preciso reconstruir 1/4 da coleção, se for dividindo mais posso ter 1/8, 1/16, 1/32 da coleção. Vou fazendo isso até que fique com poucos elementos e seja fácil modificar. Posso chegar no ponto que tem apenas um elemento.

Isto é chamado [árvore binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). É uma estrutura de dados que começa com uma raiz e vai distribuindo em pares de galhos e vai indo em níveis de galhos até chegar em uma folha que termina a árvore.

Entrando a primeira chave é colocado na raiz. Quando chega uma nova chave ele compara para ver se é maior ou igual à chave na raiz, se for maior ele liga a um nó de uma lista para um lado. Se for menor, ele coloca no outro lado.

O ideal é que na raiz tive um valor que fosse bem no meio de todos dados possíveis. Mas assim como no dicionário que a gente "nunca" abre na página certa, o índice não precisa começar no melhor ponto.

Quando vem mais dados ele vai fazendo a comparação com a raiz e depois com um do galho, se for mair que a raiz ele vai para um lado e ignora o outro. Aí essa nova chave vai para um lado ou outro desse galho. E isso vai se repetindo. Vai fazendo uma específica de pirâmide (embora possa ficar capenga de um lado).

Uma árvore fica mais ou menos assim:

[image: Árvore binária]

Mas o mais comum é vir tudo desorganizado e a árvore não ficar tão perfeitinha:

[image: Árvore desbalanceada]

Então se você tiver 32 níveis de galhos você pode acumular 4 bilhões de chaves (2 elevado a 32). O pior caso para chegar em qualquer chave é andar pelos 32 galhos. É muito rápido, e aí está a mágica.

Estruturada desta forma a coleção de dados consegue ser inserida praticamente no mesmo tempo da busca.

A árvore é como uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101) com a vantagem de dividir e conquistar. Desta forma você não tem que reconstruir a coleção toda.

E tem outra vantagem. Se você quiser "listar" toda coleção na ordem da chave (a informação que é usada para classificar os registros de dados) basta sair navegando pela árvore nó por nó que ela estará em ordem.

Existem uma quantidade imensa de algoritmos conhecidos que implementam árvores, não necessariamente binárias como um todo, mas sua base é muito parecida e até algumas partes podem ser binárias (falo mais depois), alguns:

- [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)
- [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)
- [B* tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B*-tree)
- [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)
- [Red Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Cada um tem suas vantagens e desvantagens. Alguns são muito ingênuos, outros são bem difíceis para implementar. B-Tree é o mais básico e praticamente descartado por bancos de dados.

[Respondi sobre Árvore B](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101). Esse tipo de árvore (alguma variação) é muito mais usado em índices do que a árvore puramente binária. É mais fácil você lidar com galhos e folhas múltiplas do que manter tudo certinho dividido em 2.

#### Árvore balanceada

Nem tudo são flores. Tem casos que a árvore pende para um lado, então você pode ter esse 4 bilhões de chaves e de um lado ter 2 ou 3 níveis e de outro ter dezenas ou até centenas de níveis. Ainda fica muito rápido, mas em um caso extremo você pode ter 4 bilhões de níveis e a busca ficar sequencial.

E não é tão difícil assim ter esse desbalanceamento. Se todos dados vierem em ordem, é exatamente isto que acontece. Um índice ideal deve ter o mínimo possível de níveis. Para obter isso um balanceamento se faz necessário. Já é uma algoritmo mais complexo.

Então a inserção de um novo dado não pode ser tão simples. Idealmente é preciso rebalancear os galhos para tentar ficar com todos níveis alinhados. Isto pode ser feito em cada inserção, pode fazer em blocos, pode determinar a extensão do rebalanceamento já que rebalancear um galho pode desbalancear outro mais acima. Claro que não vai rebalancear tudo em cada inserção porque isto potencialmente reconstruiria toda coleção. Dá para conviver com algum desbalanceamento por um tempo, então não precisa arrumar tudo o tempo todo. E os dados podem vir em um padrão que não desbalanceie muito. O ideal é sempre vir um maior (ou igual) e um menor para cada galho.

[Artigo Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

#### Nós e páginas

Bom, falei em nós (*nodes*), que é onde tem cada elemento. Na verdade costuma ser mais vantajoso organizar esses nós em páginas com vários deles. Esse agrupamento é útil porque a memória principal (RAM) e de massa (HDD/SSD) trabalham com páginas, então já que vai acessar a página, que tenha várias informações ali para vocês.

Seria muito complicado, acabaria ficando lento e ocuparia muito espaço tratar nó por nó.

As página não podem ser muito pequenas (em geral não compensa menor que 4K porque este é o tamanho das páginas para o sistema operacional) nem muito grandes porque essas páginas precisam ser copiadas em conjunto em algumas situações, precisam ser alocadas pelo cache, precisam ser travadas quando há acesso concorrente.

#### Composição do nó

Pensa uma coisa, um dicionário é um índice. Ele tem uma ordem. E se você quisesse ver todas entradas do dicionário em outra ordem (eu sei que é raro precisar disto), o que fazer?

No dicionário os dados principais se confundem com o índice. Mas não precisa ser assim. Você pode ter os dados principais, que não deixa de ser um índice e costuma ser chamado de *primary index* (e é sempre um índice de cobertura - ver abaixo, ou seja, é a tabela) e costuma ser montado sequencialmente por uma chave simples e controlada pelo banco de dados (`ID`) e ter vários índices secundários.

Nesses índices você tem apenas um par com uma chave (o dado que deve ser colocado em ordem) e um apontador para onde está o registro (o índice primário). Em geral a chave costuma ser maior que o apontador. O apontador costuma ser o `ID`.

Tem banco de dados que tem tamanho fixo e o número do registro não pode ser mudado, desta forma o índice primário pode ser extremamente simplificado. Mas isso é detalhe.

## Armazenamento e cache

Essas páginas podem estar na RAM ou no "disco". Dados muito acessados costumam ficar mais tempo em RAM. É o caso dos índices. ele é acessado frequentemente e precisa acessar o mais rápido possível. Tem uma série de estratégias para determinar o que "cai melhor" no cache, mas isso não vem ao caso.

Essas páginas podem ficar sempre no mesmo local (exige travamento para acesso concorrente) ou pode ser copiado toda vez que há uma alteração nela ([*copy on write*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)). Esta é uma técnica chamada [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) e dispensa o travamento, mas precisa coletar lixo (páginas não mais necessárias).

A ordem que estas páginas estão na memória ou disco não importa. Precisa ter uma maneira fácil de achá-la. E adivinha o que é usado para achar as páginas rapidamente? Árvore binária. Claro que isso depende do banco de dados, mas basicamente temos uma árvore controlando onde está tais informações.

O acesso às páginas são bem aleatórias, por isso um SSD ajuda absurdamente o desempenho de um banco de dados se comparado com um HDD. O acesso do SSD é efetivamente aleatório, como a RAM. O acesso do HDD é aleatório-sequencial, afinal é um disco que fica girando sequencialmente. Acho que imagina que em fita o banco de dados fica inviável por ser totalmente sequencial (teve época que era o que tinha).

Pensa em cada página do banco de dados como uma página do livro (especialmente um dicionário). O índice vai dizer qual é a primeira chave de cada página. Nesse momento você não precisa achar a chave mesmo, só precisa saber em que página está. Então a chave tem que ser maior que a primeira chave dessa página e menor que a primeira chave da próxima página, considerando que elas estão devidamente classificadas.

Primeiro acha em que página está e depois olha dentro da página. Em geral olhar dentro da página nem precisa de árvore.

Alguns dados podem ser maiores que uma página, por isso existem páginas especiais que são ligadas a essa página principal.

Se está com dificuldade de entender essas ligações é porque ainda não entende como listas funcionam.

## Outros tipos de índice

Este é disparado o índice mais usado por bancos de dados. Mas outras formas são usadas também. A maioria como forma de otimizar certos padrões de dados ou de buscas.

#### Hash

Existem cenários que um [índice *hash*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2016/dn133190(v=sql.130)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (porque usa uma [tabela *hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) pode ser mais interessante. Ele tem complexidade O(1), que apesar de não ser nada absurdamente melhor costuma ganhar de O(log n). O(1) é isso mesmo, não importa o tamanho ele acha o que deseja como se tivesse 1 elemento nela. Para efeito de comparação o *array* é O(1). Claro que esse O(1) não é o pior caso, mas o pior nunca acontece e mesmo o "um pouquinho pior" é raro acontecer. Idealmente suas chaves devem ser únicas.

Ele tem uma desvantagem. Não há ordem nele. Se precisar dos dados em alguma ordem, ele não fornece. A ordem é arbitrária sempre. Não serve para listagens. Mas não é só isso. Se precisar de um rebalanceamento pode ser bem demorado e inviabilizar o acesso ao índice por um tempo muito longo.

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101).

#### Índice invertido

Quando você tem o mesmo dado repetido em diversos registro do banco de dados é comum ser mais interessante o uso do [índice invertido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). Ao contrário do índice normal que você tem uma chave e um apontamento, esse tipo de índice possuí uma chave e múltiplos apontamentos. Ele indica todos os registros do banco de dados que possui aquela chave.

Eventualmente ele pode ser outras informações para ajudar a melhor classificação.

Existem alguns domínios que isso é bem interessante, mas um que é bem comum é a busca textual. Qualquer aplicação que faça buscas em texto em geral pode ter enorme ganho de performance com seu uso. Seja uma busca em dados de uma empresa, seja um buscador web mega hiper ultra super gigante.

Isso costuma chamar [*full text search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search).

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169055/101).

## Índice de cobertura

O *covering index* é apenas uma otimização, onde ele já armazena uma série de informações que normalmente serão usadas quando se aplica aquele índice, assim ele não precisa consultar a tabela principal e economiza acessos ao armazenamento de massa que é bem lento.

## Índices mapeados por bit

*Bitmap index* é útil quando você precisa fazer busca em uma determinada condição, você apenas quer que todos os registros do banco de dados que satisfaça aquela condição específica (não pode nem ter parâmetros) sejam retornados. Como toda condição, só pode dar verdadeiro ou falso. No lugar de usar chaves e apontamentos, monta-se uma sequência de bits. Cada bit esta mapeando para um registro no banco de dados em determinada ordem. Então se você quer saber se o 5482º registro atende aquela condição basta se deslocar 685 bytes e verificar o segundo bit do próximo byte.

Ele é rápido, ocupa muito pouco espaço, mas só serve para condições.

Há casos do banco de dados criar um índice mapeado em memória no momento que você está fazendo uma busca para juntar todos registros que ele deve devolver para sua *query*. É uma otimização interna.

#### Índice esparso

*Sparse index* é mais uma otimização.

Há casos que é mais interessante apontar o índice para um bloco de dados e não para o dado específico. O índice pode ser encurtado assim. É útil em casos de muita repetição de de chaves. A busca dos repetidos tende a ser sequencial, então não guarde apontamentos para todos elementos, aponte para o primeiro registro e de lá já faz a busca sequencial.

#### Índice multinível

*Multilevel index* é uma otimização onde um índice aponta para outro índice que aponta para outro índice. Desta forma pode segmentar os índices. Isso pode ajudar caber mais dados na memória ou separar a indexação em volumes de armazenamento diferentes.

#### Mais

Tem índices que mudam apenas porque permitem [condição do que deve ser indexado ou não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2325/101). A estrutura e o algoritmo não muda, mas algumas chaves não são indexadas, há um filtro.

Existem uma série de truques que podem ser adicionados ao índice para dar mais poder, flexibilidade e performance, mas que não muda nada no funcionamento do índice em si.

Outros tipos:

- [GiST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST)
- [Spatial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index)
- [RTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%2B_tree)
- [FOT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_763.htm)
- em mais...

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Grande bigown! Pretende lançar um eBook com as suas respostas? É um aula atrás da outra haha :P

Comment: @Laerte pretendo escrever alguma coisa sim, só preciso arrumar tempo.

Comment: O nome ainda vai ser ddd? Haha, quando lançar eu vou querer comprar :p, só não esquece de colocar um capítulo com as pérolas do mestre programador @OnoSendei com os devidos créditos claro kkk

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Esse seria o *blog*, não porque o que seria o DDD já existe (é um blog morto, mas já pegaram), e o DDD não é o que está pensado que é :D

Answer (score 0):

Índice você pode ver como um **sumário** de um livro, no livro através do sumário é muito mais rápido encontrar algo do que você pegar o livro e ir buscando página a página, não é mesmo? :) Essa é a ideia do índice.

Suponhamos que você tem uma tabela de 1000 registros, utilizando o indice ao utilizar a condição `..WHERE ID = 90`, ele não precisa procurar na tabela inteira, ele pega o índice e procura esse valor, já sem índice ele teria que procurar na tabela inteira até encontrar.