# O que é uma árvore B?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, ciência-da-computação, árvore

Para que tipos de problema ela é adequada? Como e por que se deve usá-la? É possível incluir um exemplo de código?

[image: B-arvorismo]

Comment: Essa é a legitima arvore B :D

Comment: Não tem mais o que responder, a foto já diz tudo :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma [árvore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) é uma estrutura de dados em um sistema de hierarquia com uma raiz, galhos e folhas, ou seja, começando em um ponto vai abrindo caminhos diferentes de acordo com o dado, até chegar no dado que deseja. Isto é muito útil porque usa o que se chama [dividir e conquistar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm). Com um determinado critério é possível ir organizando os dados em grupos de tal forma que pode selecionar esses grupos de um jeito estruturado, deixando fora as partes que não interessam. Existem dezenas ou centenas de tipos de árvores diferentes que podem ser organizadas, cada uma com característica específica atendendo uma demanda.

Uma lista não deixa de ser uma árvore, totalmente pendendo para um lado só, como ela vai só para um lado não tema essa vantagem de eliminar os itens que já sabe que não interessam. Uma árvore, simples, pura, não pode indicar um nó em nível anterior ou mais que um nó apontar para outro.

A árvore mais usada na computação é a binária, onde sempre haverá um ou dois nós ligados ao nó em nível anterior. Então vai para um lado tudo que for maior ou igual ao dado daquele nó e vai para outro lado tudo o que for menor, desta forma a cada análise feita pode se eliminar boa parte do que tem que analisar. Se a árvore estiver balanceada, você elimina metade em cada nó analisado. De metade em metade chega onde quer em poucos passos, mesmo que tenha bilhões de dados para analisar. Quanto mais dados mais eficiência a árvore dá.

[image: Árvore binária]

O problema é que é possível a árvore pender mais para um lado e no caso extremo a árvore ser uma lista sequencial. Daí surge a árvore B ([B Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)) que é uma estrutura onde é feito um balanceamento. Mais do que isso, os nós de dados, sejam galhos ou folhas são armazenados em grupos, muitas vezes chamados de *clusters* ou páginas.

O balanceamento garante que a complexidade seja O(logN) mesmo no pior caso em todas operações de leitura ou escrita. Isto costuma ficar muito próximo do tempo constante (O(1)), porque mantém sempre poucos níveis na árvore e quase todas com dois nós ligados não deixando pender para um lado. Então tanto a busca quanto as atualizações nela são muito rápidas, mantendo uma [classificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101), ao contrário de uma estrutura baseada em *hash* que dá uma performance ligeiramente melhor na maioria dos casos, mas sem uma classificação ou mesmo ordem dos dados, sema falar que a árvore facilita ter duplicidade de chaves e o *hash* cria dificuldades ou nem permite dependendo da implementação.

O agrupamento de vários dados em um nó permite que uma busca mais eficaz seja feita mesmo com dados de tamanho variável e número variável de nós de dados, e permite menos necessidade de rebalanceamento, além de se encaixar bem com a organização de memória e disco do computador, dando melhor localidade para os dados.

O rebalanceamento, quando necessário, não é algo trivial de ser feito de forma eficiente.

A estrutura não é a mais eficiente em consumo de espaço, mas a perda costuma ser pequena na maioria das implementações.

Uma boa implementação tem complexidade logarítmica para inserção em qualquer posição, remoção (individual ou em blocos), atualização (que não deixa de ser ambos) e para busca individual ou sequencial em faixas em qualquer parte, inclusive de forma reversa. Ela não costuma manter ordem de inserção sem uma técnica adicional.

[image: Árvore B]

Em uma estrutura binária simples podemos colocar 4 bilhões de nós em no máximo 32 níveis, portanto em apenas 32 consultas chegamos ao que queremos (exceto pelas consultas de sobrecargas de dados, mas isso é outro assunto), desde que devidamente balanceada. Com agrupamentos é possível reduzir isto bastante, em casos extremos (só booleanos) em 17 consultas, no máximo, mas a maioria dos casos ficará com bem menos passos, não é difícil ficar em 2 ou 3 níveis com poucos dados, ou mesmo 5 em alguns casos com muitos dados, mesmo com chave única, que é o extremo oposto de algo booleano.

Quando o tempo de acesso ao dado é pior que o tempo de processá-lo o ganho deste tipo de estrutura é considerável. Inclusive porque leitura em armazenamento de massa só ocorre em agrupamentos. Mesmo podendo ter agrupamentos pequenos (4KB), é comum preferir agrupamentos maiores em discos já que o tempo de acesso inicial, a latência, tende a ser grande e compensa ler mais coisas ao mesmo tempo e tentar achar nesse agrupamento grande qual é o próximo agrupamento a ser lido de forma mais precisa, chegando em menos passos onde se quer chegar.

Por tudo isto é a estrutura ideal para organizar bancos de dados, principalmente os índices, ainda que a tabela de dados não deixe de ser um índice. Não que ela não tenha defeitos, mas em geral as vantagens desta estrutura compensam as desvantagens, até porque as opções que não as trazem são bem piores. Essencialmente não há como obter melhor resultado. Dá para fazer algumas otimizações para reduzir o número de níveis, porque cada nível certamente é uma leitura em armazenamento de massa que é mais lenta que memória.

Obviamente que qualquer coisa que se pareça com um banco de dados e vá em armazenamento de massa se beneficia também, por exemplo o sistema de arquivo do sistema operacional.

Em memória há vantagens do seu uso em muitos casos, mas por ter baixa localidade outras opções podem ter ganho mesmo que tenha que analisar mais informações.

Existem variações de árvore que buscam o mesmo objetivo, mas com complexidade muito grande de implementação e com outros problemas. Variações de árvore binária pode melhorar a forma de balanceamento ou a forma de armazenar os nós atendendo uma necessidade mais específica. Por exemplo há B+ tree, B* tree, UB tree, B*+ tree.

Tem variações que funcionam melhor com o dado que já é classificado, caso típico de chave primária sequencial, algumas funcionam melhor com dados completamente embaralhados.

Há controvérsias sobre o que o B significa. Usualmente entendemos como balanceada, mas é só intuição. Na verdade os termos usados na definição geral da estrutura não são sempre consistentes.

Existem implementações diferentes, cada uma com suas vantagens e desvantagens. Uma das mais usadas é a [Red Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) é outra.

Implantar uma estrutura e algoritmos de árvore são triviais, mas algo eficiente e robusto pode ser um trabalho bem complicado. A boa notícia é que por ser algo tão estudado você não precisa inventar nada.

Obviamente que uma série de detalhes podem ser trabalhados para atender certas demandas, como ser melhor para armazenamento de massa ou principal (RAM), ter concorrência no acesso, poder acessar em ordem reversa, economizar espaço em detrimento de alguma outra característica, carregamento de grandes volumes de dados já classificados, melhorar o trabalho de balanceamento, etc.

[image: Mais um exemplo da árvore com as folhas finais de dados]

[Brinque com isto](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/BTree.html).

Uma [implementação e exercícios em português](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/estruturas-de-dados/aulas/B-trees.html) para se aprofundar.

[Veja mais sobre a navegação em árvores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

```js
const NKEYS = 4;

function arrayOfSize(size) {
    var a = Array(size);

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
        a[i] = null;

    return a;
}

function BTreeNode() {
    this._keyCount = 0;
    this._keys = arrayOfSize(NKEYS);
    this._childs = arrayOfSize(NKEYS+1);
}

BTreeNode.prototype.isLeaf = function() {
    return (this._childs[0] === null);
};

BTreeNode.prototype.isFull = function() {
    return (this._keyCount === NKEYS);
};

BTreeNode.prototype.keyCount = function() {
    return this._keyCount;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.add = function(key) {
    if (this.isLeaf()) {
        if (this.isFull()) {
            return this.split(key, null);
        }
        else {
            this.insertKey(key);
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        var child = this.getChildContaining(key);
        
        var split = child.add(key);
        if (!split) return null;

        if (this.isFull()) {
            // split this node
            return this.split(split.key, split.right);
        }
        else {
            this.insertSplit(split);
            return null;
        }
    }
};

BTreeNode.prototype.insertKey = function(key) {
    console.assert( this.isLeaf() );

    // perform insertion sort on keys
    
    var pos = this.keyCount();
    var keys = this._keys;

    while (pos > 0 && keys[pos-1] > key) {
        keys[pos] = keys[pos-1];
        pos--;
    }

    keys[pos] = key;
    this._keyCount += 1;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.insertSplit = function(split) {
    // splited child
    var child = split.left;

    // insert key with right child poped up from
    // child node
    
    // case A: first child was split
    if (child === this._childs[0]) {
        for (var i = this._keyCount; i > 0; i--)
            this._keys[i] = this._keys[i-1];
        this._keys[0] = split.key;

        for (var i = this._keyCount+1; i > 1; i--)
            this._childs[i] = this._childs[i-1];
        this._childs[0] = child;
        this._childs[1] = split.right;
    }
    
    // case B: [key][split-child] (split child is on the right)
    else {
        var pos = this._keyCount;
        while (pos > 0 && this._childs[pos] !== child) {
            this._keys[pos] = this._keys[pos-1];
            this._childs[pos+1] = this._childs[pos];
            pos--;
        }

        this._keys[pos] = split.key;
        this._childs[pos+1] = split.right;
    }

    // rest
    this._keyCount += 1;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.getChildContaining = function(key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.keyCount(); i += 1) {
        if (key <= this._keys[i]) {
            return this._childs[i];
        }
    }

    return this._childs[this.keyCount()];
};

BTreeNode.prototype.split = function(key, keyRightChild) {
    var left = this;
    var right = new BTreeNode();

    // temp storage for keys and childs
    var keys = this._keys.slice();
    keys.push(null);

    var childs = this._childs.slice();
    childs.push(null);

    // find new key position
    var pos = keys.length-1;
    while (pos > 0 && keys[pos-1] > key) {
        keys[pos] = keys[pos-1];
        childs[pos+1] = childs[pos];
        pos--;
    }

    keys[pos] = key;
    childs[pos+1] = keyRightChild;

    // split into two childs and key
    var medianIndex = Math.floor(keys.length / 2);
    var medianKey = this._keys[medianIndex];
    var i;

    // fix left child keys and childs
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (i < medianIndex) {
            left._childs[i] = childs[i];
            left._keys[i] = keys[i];
        }
        else if (i === medianIndex) {
            left._childs[i] = childs[i];
            left._keys[i] = null;
        }
        else {
            left._childs[i] = this._keys[i] = null;
        }
    }
    left._keyCount = medianIndex;

    // fix right child keys and childs
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (i > medianIndex) {
            right._keys[i-medianIndex-1] = keys[i];
            right._childs[i-medianIndex-1] = childs[i];
            right._keyCount += 1;
        }
    }
    right._childs[keys.length-medianIndex-1] = childs[keys.length];

    return ({ left:left, key:medianKey, right:right });
};

BTreeNode.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    if (this.isLeaf()) {
        return this.removeKey(key);
    }
    else {
        var keyIndex = this.indexOfKey(key);
        var child;

        if (keyIndex === (-1)) {
            child = this.getChildContaining(key);
            var result = child.remove(key);

            this.rebalance(this._childs.indexOf(child));
            return result;
        }
        else {
            // replace key with max key from left child
            child = this._childs[keyIndex];
            this._keys[keyIndex] = child.extractMax();

            this.rebalance(keyIndex);
            return true;
        }
    }
};

BTreeNode.prototype.rebalance = function(childIndex) {
    const MIN_NKEYS = (NKEYS/2);

    var child = this._childs[childIndex];
    if (child.keyCount() >= MIN_NKEYS) {
        return;
    }

    // borrow from left child
    if (childIndex) {
        var leftChild = this._childs[childIndex-1];
        if (leftChild.keyCount() > MIN_NKEYS) {
            var lastKey = leftChild._keys[leftChild.keyCount()-1];
            var lastChild = leftChild._child[leftChild.keyCount()];
            leftChild._keyCount--;

            var key = this._keys[childIndex-1];
            this._keys[childIndex-1] = lastKey;

            for (var i = child._keyCount-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                child._keys[i+1] = child._keys[i];
            }
            child._keys[0] = key;

            for (var i = child._keyCount; i >= 0; i--) {
                child._childs[i+1] = child._childs[i];
            }
            child._childs[0] = lastChild;
            child._keyCount++;

            return;
        }
    }
    
    // borrow from right child
    if (childIndex < this.keyCount()) {
        var rightChild = this._childs[childIndex+1];
        if (rightChild.keyCount() > MIN_NKEYS) {
            var firstKey = rightChild._keys[0];
            var firstChild = rightChild._childs[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < rightChild.keyCount()-1; i++) {
                rightChild._keys[i] = rightChild._keys[i+1];
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < rightChild.keyCount(); i++) {
                rightChild._childs[i] = rightChild._childs[i+1];
            }

            rightChild._keyCount--;

            child._keys[child.keyCount()] = this._keys[childIndex];
            this._keys[childIndex] = firstKey;
            child._childs[child.keyCount()+1] = firstChild;
            child._keyCount++;

            return;
        }
    }
   
    // merge
    if (childIndex) {
        // merge left and current
        childIndex -= 1;
    }

    // childIndex will point to the *left* node of two merged nodes
    
    var merged = this.mergeChilds(childIndex);
    
    for (var i = childIndex; i < this._keyCount-1; i += 1) {
        this._keys[i] = this._keys[i+1];
    }
    for (var i = childIndex; i < this._keyCount; i += 1) {
        this._childs[i] = this._childs[i+1];
    }
    this._keyCount--;
    this._childs[childIndex] = merged;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.mergeChilds = function(leftIndex) {
    var key = this._keys[leftIndex];

    var left = this._childs[leftIndex];
    var right = this._childs[leftIndex+1];

    left._keys[left._keyCount] = key;
    left._keyCount++;

    // copy right keys and childs into left
    for (var i = 0; i < right._keyCount; i++) {
        left._childs[left._keyCount] = right._childs[i];
        left._keys[left._keyCount] = right._keys[i];
        left._keyCount += 1;
    }

    left._childs[left._keyCount] = right._childs[right._keyCount];

    return left;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.extractMax = function() {
    var key;

    if (this.isLeaf()) {
        key = this._keys[this._keyCount-1];
        this._keyCount--;
    }
    else {
        var child = this._childs[this._keyCount];
        key = child.extractMax();

        this.rebalance(this._keyCount);
    }

    return key;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.indexOfKey = function(key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this._keyCount; i += 1) {
        if (this._keys[i] === key) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return (-1);
};

BTreeNode.prototype.removeKey = function(key) {
    console.assert( this.isLeaf() );
 
    var keyIndex = this.indexOfKey(key);
    if (keyIndex === (-1))
        return false;

    // delete key
    for (var i = keyIndex+1; i < this._keyCount; i += 1) {
        this._keys[i-1] = this._keys[i];
    }

    this._keyCount--;
    return true;
};

BTreeNode.prototype.toString = function(indentOpt) {
    const INDENT_STRING = '  ';

    indentOpt = indentOpt || '';

    if (this.isLeaf()) {
        return indentOpt + '[' + 
            this._keys.slice(0, this.keyCount()).join(', ') + 
            ']';
    }

    var str = '';

    var childIndent = indentOpt + INDENT_STRING;
    var childStrings = this._childs.
        slice(0, this.keyCount()+1).
        map(function(child) {
            return child.toString(childIndent);
        });

    str = indentOpt + '[\n' + childStrings[0] + '\n';
    for (var i = 1; i < childStrings.length; i += 1) {
        str += childIndent + this._keys[i-1].toString() + '\n' + 
            childStrings[i] + '\n';
    }
    str += indentOpt + ']';

    return str;
};

BTreeNode.fromSplit = function(split) {
    var node = new BTreeNode();

    node._keyCount = 1;
    node._keys[0] = split.key;
    node._childs[0] = split.left;
    node._childs[1] = split.right;

    return node;
};

function BTree() {
    this._root = new BTreeNode();   
}

BTree.prototype.add = function(key) {
    var curr = this._root;

    var split = curr.add(key);
    if (!split) return;

    this._root = BTreeNode.fromSplit(split);
};

BTree.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    var removed = this._root.remove(key);

    if (this._root.keyCount() === 0 && this._root._childs[0]) {
        this._root = this._root._childs[0];
    }

    return removed;
};

BTree.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this._root.toString();
};

// ------------------------------------
// TEST PROGRAM

var btree = new BTree();

var a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20];
var a2 = [4,2,7,1,5,3,8];

var a = a1;

a.forEach(function(v) {
    // console.log('----------------------------------');
    // console.log('ADDING ' + v + ' TO TREE');
    // console.log('');

    btree.add(v);
   // console.log(btree.toString());
});

console.log(' --- BEFORE REMOVING --- ');
console.log(btree.toString());

a.forEach(function(v) {
    console.log('----------------------------------');
    console.log('REMOVING ' + v + ' FROM TREE');
    console.log('');

    console.assert( btree.remove(v) );
    console.log(btree.toString());
});
```

[Fonte](https://gist.github.com/marcin-chwedczuk/105b9e2c99e3ba48d4e1cd51f2a35907).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: `Ainda vou melhorar até porque é algo que gosto muito e vou tentar colocar exemplo, ainda que um código legal será meio grande e complexo.` Por favor! Eu adoro as suas respostas :)

Comment: @Renan e eu adoro as suas :)