# Quais as diferenças entre os algoritmos HASH e BTREE usados em um índice?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, índices

Eu percebi que posso criar dois tipo de índices para um determinando campo no HeidiSQL, que usam o algoritmo `HASH` ou `BTREE`, veja abaixo:

[image: tipo de index]

Veja o código CREATE de uma tabela de exemplo para a ilustração:

```
CREATE TABLE `pessoa` (
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `index_nome` (`nome`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `index_email` (`email`) USING HASH
)
```

Sendo assim, eu fiquei com algumas dúvidas a respeito desses dois tipos de algoritmos que podem ser usados.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é o algoritmo HASH?
2. O que e o algoritmo BTREE?
3. Quais as diferenças entre HASH e BTREE?

Comment: `HASH` é a tabela de espalhamento; dado um conjunto de dados, eles geram um número X qualquer, então só consultar na tabela se existe algum elemento com esse número X. `BTREE` por sua vez só se aplica a elementos passíveis de ordenação absoluta; no lugar de consultar uma tabela, se consulta uma árvore B.

Comment: Ah, não confunda "árvore B" com "árvore binária"...

Comment: Neste caso o BTREE esta relacionado a árvore binária?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/64969

Comment: o relacionamento entre árvores B e árvores binárias é o mesmo relacionamento entre tamareiras e pinheiros: ambas são árvores. A ideia da árvore B envolve páginas de tamanho arbitrário e balanceamento dos nós, de tal modo que qualquer folha não raiz tenha pelo menos metade da página preenchida. Mais detalhes na pergunta (e nas suas respostas) que eu linkei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já [respondi no contexto do PostgreSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101).

Já [dei detalhes sobre Btree](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101) (ok, ainda preciso completar).

Já [falei sobre o código de *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184019/101).

Já [foi respondido sobre as tabelas *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/101).

A [documentação mostra a diferença](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html). Na forma escrita parece que não querem que use o *hash*. Só mostram desvantagens. O que é algo bem realista.

É muito raro ele ser útil, ainda mais em disco onde costuma forçar muito mais leitura. A tradução literal de *hash table* é tabela de espalhamento, e qualquer coisa que fique espalhada é ruim para acessar em certas mídias, ou prejudica o cache resultando mais *thrashing*.

A principal desvantagem é só poder comparar a igualdade, o que traz outras implicações como não poder manter a ordem, que vai trazendo uma cascata de implicações.

Mas se for na memória e só precisa testar a igualdade e o acesso a cada elemento costuma ser individual mesmo e há poucas colisões de chave, seja porque o dado original não se repete ou o resultado da função *hash* não repete muito, aí ele consegue ser mais rápido que qualquer árvore binária ou árvore B. Se tiver muita escrita quase certamente haverá ganhos nessa operação (não nos raros piores casos).

Uma árvore B pode ter muita manutenção interna em tabelas com muita escrita, mas a leitura é sempre muito otimizada.

O índice *hash* só é útil se a pessoa entende bem todas implicações e fez testes que demonstram ganho claro. Por isso fica quase escondido e limitado a certos *engines* do MySQL.

Existe um índice *hash* interno que o banco de dados usa quando ele entende que é melhor para organizar resultados de consultas, mas é um detalhe que não interessa para quem usa o MySQL.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).