# O que são hints de índice?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, índices

Vi um comentário do @RicardoPontual que mencionava **hints de índice baseados em densidade**

> sua pergunta parece bem confusa.. começa com uma coisa muito básica
>   como "como faço uma procedure no sql server", que é simples demais de
>   achar no Google e termina falando em **hints de índice baseando em
>   densidade**, uma coisa bem avançada, não faz muito sentido pra mim

Isso me gerou algumas duvidas, sedo elas:

- O que são *hints* de índice?
- O que são *hints* de índice baseados em densidade?
- Existem outros tipos de *hints*?
- Seria possível adição de exemplos, independente do banco de dados?

<sub>obs¹:Se tiver algo a mais sobre o assunto, fique a vontade para adicionar</sub>

<sub>obs²:Se usei algum termo erroneamente, podem corrigir na pergunta</sub>

Comment: Em Oracle é uma dica que você , unidade de carbono , de forma humilde , com a devida vênia , dá para o analisador de execução, por experiência digo em poucos casos funciona , mas já tive melhoras significativas com um simples "hint". https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i8327

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se o contexto é esse, mas *hint* (dica) é uma forma do programador/usuário do banco de dados dizer como ele quer que a *query* seja executada, informando o(s) índice(s) a ser(em) usado(s) e de que forma serão aproveitados. Nem todos os sistemas de bancos de dados possuem essa funcionalidade, já por isso não dá para colocar exemplos.

Geralmente não é recomendado usar, a não ser que você tenha um domínio de álgebra relacional muito forte e tenha conhecimento dos dados existentes e sabe que a sua configuração não mudará significativamente ao ponto da dica prejudicar mais que ajudar. Quase sempre o banco de dados fará um serviço melhor. Só deve usar quando claramente ele está errado e você pode dar uma dica mais adequada. E ele não é obrigado a seguir. Sem entendimento profundo do funcionamento do banco de dados causará mais mal do que bem.

Pode ser que essa dica esteja indicando a densidade de dados para que o índice seja usado, geralmente isso só é necessário quando precisa da performance logo de início, depois o banco de dados pode produzir uma estatística melhor, ou nem precisa. Mas não sei se algum banco de dados permite algo exatamente assim.

Não sei o contexto, pode ser que estava falando de densidade como o [índice *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258193/101) ([outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101)). Ou um método de uso de índice baseado em espalhamento.

[Documentação do SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).